# Disable "where" under different conditions in the select in the apex oracle

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

look at me t interactive report in apex oracle, I have there selection by data area. I also have a spreadsheet with users there is a ROLE column, since ROLE is 30, it means that the user is an administrator. I want that when in the program the admin the selection was not required. So what can I do ??

```html
select ID,
       DATA,
       NAME
  from SEC_TRANSFER_SEALS
where  data_area = (select name from SEC_USERS_LIST where login =   LOWER(:APP_USER) ) 
order by data desc
```

```html
user_table vaiue:id,LOGIN, PASSWORD, ROLE
(2, LOGIN, PASSWORD, 30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways this can be done:

#### OPTION 1. Add the admin check directly to the query:

```
select ID,
       DATA,
       NAME
  from SEC_TRANSFER_SEALS
where  (data_area = (select name from SEC_USERS_LIST where login =   LOWER(:APP_USER) )
or 30 = (
   select u.role from user_table u where u.login = lower(:APP_USER)
))
order by data desc
```

The downside to this approach is that the code needs to be added everywhere you need to check the user's admin access.

#### OPTION 2. Application Item

Create an Application Item (under Shared Components), e.g. USER_ROLE_ID

Create an Application Computation (also under Shared Components) that sets USER_ROLE_ID to the result of a query, e.g.

```
select u.role from user_table u where u.login = lower(:APP_USER)
```

Now you can refer to the user's role anywhere, e.g.

```
select ID,
       DATA,
       NAME
  from SEC_TRANSFER_SEALS
where  (data_area = (select name from SEC_USERS_LIST where login =   LOWER(:APP_USER) )
or :USER_ROLE_ID=30 )
order by data desc
```